# Python Pandas - Replacing cell value matching regular expression

Tags: python, pandas, regex

New to Python and regex - I am trying to write a code to replace values in a column of my data frame which match a particular pattern.

Some sample values in my data frame are: Self- Employed, Self-Employeed,Self -employed,Retired (Self-emplyed)

The pattern I have is - If the value contains words starting with Self- or Self - or Self (space) [Ignore the case of self] then replace the entire value with "Self Employed"

Below is what i have tried -

```
data = pd.read_csv('loan.csv',keep_default_na=False)
data['emp_title']=data['emp_title'].replace('^Self','Self Employed',regex=True)
```

There are 2 problems -

1. The regex seems incorrect. It is finding all the words starting with self but not contains. And it is taking into consideration the case of the word.
2. Replace function seems to be replacing only the word "Self" and not the full value. For eg: If the value in my cell is "Self employed", python seems to replace only Self and makes the value "Self Employed employed"

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change to this code:

```bash
data = pd.read_csv('loan.csv',keep_default_na=False)
data['emp_title']=data['emp_title'].replace(r'(?i)\bself\b(?:\s*-\s*employed)?(?!\s+Employed\b)', 'Self Employed', regex=True)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/t2pQqa/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `r'...'`: Raw string
- `(?i)`: Ignore case mode
- `\bSelf\b`: Match complete word `Self` (case ignore)
- `(?:\s*-\s*employed)?`: An *optional match* to match `-employed`
- `(?!\s+Employed\b)`: Negative lookahead to assert that `Self` is not followed by 1+ whitespace and word `Employed`

Comment: This is again replacing values for "self-employed" to "Self Employed-employed" which is incorrect. It should replace "self-employed" to "Self Employed"

Comment: That is because question didn't include case of `self-employed` being present in input. You had only mentioned `If the value in my cell is "Self employed"`. I will make an edit to my answer but please edit your question.

Comment: The pattern I have is - If the value contains words starting with Self- or Self - or Self (space) [Ignore the case of self] then replace the entire value with "Self Employed"

------- ------------ So anything starting/containing Self- or Self - or Self (with a space) and ignore the case of Self in all instances that is what I meant.

Comment: ok answer updated